# I need to get handles on PowerPoint Shapes using Windows API so that I can catch events on the shape?

Tags: c#, winapi, event-handling, shapes, office-addins

I'm writing a PowerPoint AddIn in C# and need to know when shapes are deleted or when mouse events occur on the shapes.  I've use the Windows API SetWindowsHookEx to get mouse events for the application, and combined this with the WindowSelectionChange event, that is exposed by PowerPoint, to know when a shape may have moved (or been resized).  I have looked for Windows API calls that might get a handle on the shapes and then enable me to add a hook(?) to catch events on a shape by shape basis but can't find anything out there.  I'm very happy to incorporate unmanaged code in my AddIn if I have to (as per my use of SetWindowsHookEx).  Can anyone help?

Comment: I have a feeling the individual shapes are NOT individual windows with individual window handles. [That would be a waste of](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/15/395866.aspx) [a very limited (on Windows) resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/17/3903614.aspx). See if you can control PowerPoint via COM, OLE, or VBA. (Other than that I don't know the answer.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I think you're right - I've done some further digging and used the EnumWindows function - no shapes came up (strangely ComboBoxes do!).  I'm now thinking I may have to run a separate thread that monitors the shapes on the slide (for deletion etc), but this seems a bit like overkill.  My thoughts re getting a handle (of some kind) were that PowerPoint is able to catch events on individual shapes, which I'd presumed were coming from the OS, so in theory I should also be able to hook into these events.  Any further thoughts on how to proceed would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonSmith you asked this a long time ago but maybe you found more insights to share? I'm really curious how one could set hooks per shape!

Comment: Hi Cilvic, afraid that I didn’t find any way of catching events on individual shapes and relied on the Windows mouse events and the PowerPoint events - a bit of a long winded work around! Sorry couldn’t be more helpful - let me know if you find anything.